# Are Centrum Tablets allowed in Islam (Halal or Haram)?

Tags: halal-haram, food, pork

Some of the [Centrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrum_%28multivitamin%29) tablets are made from vitamins of pork it says on their official website.

I want to know if they can be used for medical treatment for a better health or not? If not, and there is no alternative, then let the person be sick?

Is it strictly prohibited or up to some percentages of pork are allowed in food items?

Please support your stances with authentic references.

Comment: Kindly explain what are centrum tablets? Why are they used?

Comment: Centrum has vitamins and proteins used for weakness and purposes, mostly prescribed to old people.

Comment: Surely, there are alternatives.

Comment: assuming that there are none, what then?

Comment: Please consult a Muslim doctor in your area. He will better know about the alternatives.

Comment: i live in a muslim country and all the doctors here are muslim and yet they prescribe centrum.

Comment: @anas Please cite (using hyperlink) their official website.

Answer (score 1):

Pork from pigs are not allowed, even if its slaughtered in a "halal" way, so don't buy them.

You should consider going to the doctor and tell him/her that it is Haram if the doctor is muslim as you say.

The only way you can buy them is if your life is depending on it, so not just sickness,( because Allah can cure you without vitamins IF you just ask).

However if you are going die if you do not buy it then it's allowed, but you have to ask Allah's forgiveness afterwards because it wasn't allowed at first.

There are alternatives, I don't know what doctors you have there but they are surely didn't get the right education if they say there isn't an alternative.

(Try honey, black seeds, or zamzam water these are natural ways to cure something)

Allah knows best,